# Using CGEventTapCreate Trouble with parameters in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, quartz-graphics

I am trying to trap keypresses using a CGEventTapCreate etc in Swift. I want to do this so that when my toddler is using a program the Mac, I can limit which keys do something. I appreciate that I need to enable assistive technology to get CGEventTap to work

I am having trouble understanding what I need to do in Swift to get the final parameter in the call. Essentially, I do not understand part of the documentation at quartz event [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreate)

Specifically the final parameter which is described by

> refcon: A pointer to user-defined data. This pointer is passed into
>   the callback function specified in the callback parameter.

Here is my code missing the final parameter from the call

```
@IBAction func interceptKeyboard(sender: NSButton) {


    CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, CGEventMask((kCGEventKeyDown) | (kCGEventKeyUp)), MyCallBack: kCGHIDEventTap, )

}

func MyCallBack(myLocation:CGEventTapLocation) -> Void{
    //do Nowt
}
```

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891002/how-do-you-use-cgeventtapcreate-in-swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a while ago, but I think when you look at the type of CGEventTapCallback, you see that it is a CFunctionPointer:

```
typealias CGEventTapCallBack = CFunctionPointer<((CGEventTapProxy, 
CGEventType, CGEvent!, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>!)>
```

At the moment you can't create these in Swift, so you have to dip into objective-c, create a function there, which can then call an equivalent function in Swift, see here:

[Objective-C Wrapper for CFunctionPointer to a Swift Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138658/objective-c-wrapper-for-cfunctionpointer-to-a-swift-closure)

I ended up writing the whole of this stuff in Objective-C...

Comment: Thanks for that. Should have marked you up ages ago.