# How to implement C-Style callback functions using swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, callback, iokit

I found an example for `IOKit`:

```
var notification:io_object_t

let matching:NSDictionary = IOServiceNameMatching("IODisplayWrangler").takeRetainedValue()
let displayWrangler = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, matching)
let notificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(kIOMasterPortDefault)
    IOServiceAddInterestNotification(notificationPort, displayWrangler, kIOGeneralInterest, displayPowerNotificationsCallback, nil, &notification)

CFRunLoopAddSource (CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notificationPort), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
   IOObjectRelease (displayWrangler);
```

The above example is clear to me - so far. But `IOServiceAddInteresNotification` wants a callback function. In  it's simple to do this, by implementing the C-Style function somewhere in the `.m`-file.

The documentation says that I have to use a callback of type `IOServiceInterestCallback`.

In C-Style it is defined as follows:

```
typedef void ( *IOServiceInterestCallback)( void *refcon, io_service_t service, uint32_t messageType, void *messageArgument );
```

And on objC everything seems to work out perfectly. 
What is the equivalent solution in swift? How do I declare the callback function without creating a C or objC file for this?

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: objective-c and swift's function and block (closure) types can generally be used interchangeably. have you tried writing a swift function that matches the required signature and using that?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this idea. But swift complained about the void* and uint32_t (which don't exist) why I didn't manage to implement it.

Comment: IOServiceInterestCallback is defined in swift. Do you know the syntax how to use a predefined function prototype to implement the callback using something like "func IOServiceInterestCallback displayPowerNotificationsCallback { (...) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create C function like callbacks in Swift as closures are not compatible with `CFunctionPointer`. You can implement some workaround in Objective-C or C. Example is describe in [Objective-C Wrapper for CFunctionPointer to a Swift Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138658/objective-c-wrapper-for-cfunctionpointer-to-a-swift-closure)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That means I always need to use objC wrappers just for the callback. However, good to know that closures are not compatible with CFunctionPointer.