# Trying to find a Swift MIDI callback workaround

Tags: swift, midi, coremidi

There is still an issue with defining callbacks in CoreMIDI with Swift, so the workaround is to use Objective-C. I found this answer, but I cannot figure out how to use `MIDIReadProcCallback.setOnCallback({ (packetList: MIDIPacketList) in ... })` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26139259/616873.

I cannot comment on the specific answer for more clarification because my rep is not 50, so if anyone can point me to some sample code or further clarification, I would be **very** appreciative.

Comment: The answer is correct, so what problem are you having? Just do what the answer tells you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [blog post](http://bit.ly/1dMMXgS) and github repo with a working example. The Swift code uses objc as a trampoline for the function pointers.

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually have been watching your blog in hopes for a workaround! Nice solution for the lack of the next packet function.(I would give you rep, but I'm below the minimum to do that.)

Comment: And I thought only my cat read my blog :) I used one of my developer support questions to Apple on this. They responded that yeah, callbacks don't work in Swift, so keep the trampoline. Sigh. Glad it helped you.